# Create directory tree on file write

Tags: python

I'm using `pathlib.Path` and when I run my script I want to write to a log file in a new directory.

To accomplish this, the file path is defined as:

```
p = Path.home() / '.app' / 'logs' / 'foo.log'
```

However, in order to write to `foo.log` the `mkdir()` method must be called first.

Is there not a way to create required directories for a file on write if they do not exist? That is, the first time `foo.log` would be opened for writing, create the `.app/logs` tree.

Comment: if this is for logging why not use pythons builtin `logging` library?

Comment: @alex I was already aware of how to create the directories using `pathlib.Path.mkdir()`, but I was wondering if the library support implicit creating of parents needed by a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually pathlib's [`Path.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) function has an optional `parents` argument which when set to `True` will create all folders in that Path. In your case this could work:

```
p = Path.home() / '.app' / 'logs' / 'foo.log'
p.parent.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)
```

Adding the `exist_ok` argument as True will not raise any exceptions if the path exists already.

If you *really* need to make it work implicitly, then you could just wrap the `__truediv__` function of `Path` but I really don't recommend doing this:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def tree(self,other):
        self.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)
        return f(self,other)
    return tree

Path.__truediv__ = decorator(Path.__truediv__)

p = Path.home() / '.app' / 'logs' / 'foo.log'
```

This will call the `mkdir` on the left side of the path, because the right side is not decided if it's a directory or a file yet.

Comment: I am aware of this method, however I was wondering if `pathlib` supported implicit creation of parents, instead of explicitly calling this.

Comment: You could just make a function that creates the directory using this function on the file's parent folder.

Comment: One way to make this maybe a bit more compact is to define the full path as `p`, and then do: `p.parent.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)` and avoid the re-assign of `p`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that in a one liner as you say.

You aren't writing the file with pathlib, either. You are, probably, using the .write function, and  needs a parent directory to exist.

Comment: I open using `p.open('w')`, which throws `FileNotFoundError` since the parents don't exist. I was hoping `pathlib` supported implicitly creating necessary parents.

Comment: You are welcome to submit a PR for it. And to upvote my answer, since it understood what you wanted.